# WS-Security in Delphi XE8

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, ws-security

I'm trying to acces a webservice with WS-Security in Delphi, but i'm not really sure how to do it

This is the XML that i'm sending right now

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
     <NS1:Security xmlns:NS1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
       <Timestamp xsi:nil="true"/>
       <BinarySecurityToken xsi:nil="true"/>
       <NS1:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="">
         <Username xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">MyUsername</Username>
         <NS1:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">MyPass</NS1:Password>
         <Nonce xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"></Nonce>
         <Created xsi:nil="true"/>
       </NS1:UsernameToken>
       <Signature xsi:nil="true"/>
     </NS1:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body> 
    <GetUsername xsi:nil="true"/>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I get a timeout that i'm pretty sure is due the credentials. 
I'm calling the functions of the webservice using the code generated by the WSDL importer of delphi and a HTTPRIO

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try SoapUI or a Proxy to detect differences between working and non-working requests?

Comment: Yes, but i can't see how to authenticate in SoapUI

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29129351/800214

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last week. **The problem is that your password is actually a clear-text password that was provided surely to access your developer portal's management account** (I made that mistake). The actual REAL password is an encrypted security that the webservice developer generates and sends you. You have to either copy-paste the security key as the password element value or save it to a text file.

I could bet you got the following message when your tried to call your webservice method: `UsernameToken Authentication failed`.